# Does the magnitude of gravity stay the same at all points along the geoid

Tags: geodesy

And how does this differ from the gravitational potential along the geoid (which is equal).

Comment: On a rotating object that equilibrates hydrostatically to an oblate spheroid such as Earth, the gravitational acceleration would be greater at the Equator. But your weight there would be offset partially by centrifugal force from the rotation, so you would register more weight on a bathroom scale at the poles.